# Add external root folder with subfolders for resources for each app to tomcat (classpath)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

I created folder **resources** in %TOMCAT_HOME% for static resources (*.xml, *.properties, etc...).

The deploy of my app (app1) create in %TOMCAT_HOME%/resources the folder **app1-resources** with the own files *.xml, *.properties... of my app1.

In %TOMCAT_HOME%/conf/catalina.properties I added:

```
shared.loader=${catalina.base}/resources
```

But when I access to any file with the classpath:

```
(...)
<value>classpath:app1-resources/conf.properties</value>
(...)
```

Or:

```
(...)
@ImportResource("classpath:app1-resources/spring-config.xml")
(...)
```

It fail!!! Because not found resources...

If I change the configuration to:

```
shared.loader=${catalina.base}/resources/app1-resources
```

And change the access to those to:

```
(...)
<value>classpath:conf.properties</value>
(...)
```

Or:

```
(...)
@ImportResource("classpath:spring-config.xml")
(...)
```

It works.

My problem is if I deploy more than one app in the same tomcat, I want to access to the resources of each app independently. For example:

App1:

- In java: classpath:app1-resources/config.xml
- I create a folder for the resources of my app1: %TOMCAT_HOME%/resources/app1-resources/config.xml

App2:

- In java: classpath:app2-resources/config.xml
- I create a folder for the resources of my app2: %TOMCAT_HOME%/resources/app2-resources/config.xml

My question is: **Can I specify a root directory which my resources lies underneath it (in a custom folder for each app)?**

Anybody can solve my problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Specify it in `shared.loader` or `common.loader` property of `/conf/catalina.properties`.

Comment: Thanks but it isn´t a good solution for me, my problem is: Can I specify my root directory Which resources lies underneath it (in a custom folder for each app)?